# Why I get `SendFailure` on Kusama?

Tags: kusama, xcm

Here is my call:

https://crab-parachain.subscan.io/extrinsic/284069-2

With the same params, I can send the message to Rococo through XCM.

The error's description is:

```
/// There was some other issue (i.e. not to do with routing) in sending the 
message. Perhaps
/// a lack of space for buffering the message.
```

So, what the other issue could be? And I don't have too much knowledge about the `lack of space for buffering the message`. What does that mean?

Btw, I'm on `polkadot-v0.9.16`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why the `SafeXCMVersion` is empty. I have already set it in the genesis.

Never mind, use `force_xcm_version` and `force_default_xcm_version` to fix this.